# EF Core 3.1 Add Migration on specific DB Context

Tags: c#, oracle, entity-framework, .net-core, ef-core-3.1

I have 2 EF Core DBContexts in my WebAPI project.

One is an OracleContext - Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore(2.19.70).

The OracleContext is an existing database where I have already made repositories for querying read-only data.

Second is an SQLServerContext - EFCore(3.1.5)

The SQLServerContext is a code-first approach for writing the rest of the app's functionality.

Whenever I try to run Add-Migration InitialCreate -Context SQLServerContext -OutputDir Migrations\SqlServerMigrations it gives me an error:

> Method 'get_Info' in type
>   'Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Infrastructure.Internal.OracleOptionsExtension'
>   from assembly 'Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore, Version=2.0.19.1,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342' does not have an
>   implementation.

I believe Add-Migration is also trying to execute the OracleContext but I wanted the SQLServerContext only to generate migration files, How can I achieve this?

[EDIT] 
- Each DBContexts lives on its own dotnet core library classes.
- WebAPI project is the startup project.

Comment: [From here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58301685/), this is likely due to breaking changes in EfCore 3.0 and later not working with older providers. You'll either need to downgrade EfCore to 2.x, or you might try the [Oracle 3.19.0-beta1](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore/)

Comment: I think I'm almost close to solving it after downgrading the SQLServerContext project to 2.2.6. Now I am facing: Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Design.OperationException: Unable to create an object of type 'SQLServerContext'. For the different patterns supported at design time, see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851728

Answer (score 4):

For Add Migration In Asp.Net Core 3.1 in visual studio use below code:

```
Add-Migration yourMigrationName -Context youSpecificContextName
```

Answer (score 1):

Need to specify the context. In terminal, switch to project which contains migration folder. Use below command

```
dotnet ef migrations add --context YourApp.YourAppDbContext '<MigrationName>'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the fully qualified name with namespace, It takes the class name as well, but I think in your case EF Core is choosing the other context.

Comment: I tried just like you said to use like -Context ProjectName.Folder.SQLServerContext but it didn't work. I also tried putting typo for in the context parameter but the result is the same.